# How to load images from a directory using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am toying with the following code trying to take images from a set directory, and preload them. I do not want to load the images into a div, but rather preload them in the memory using the normal:

```
new Image().src = "/wp-content/themes/NCHERM_Theme/images/home4-events.jpg";
```

I am rather new to jquery so looking for some help to finalize this:

```
window.onload = function($) {
    var folder = "images/preload";

    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            //go through each item in folder
            $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
                //take each item and run into the normal preload method
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // preload images
                    new Image().src = filename;
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    });  
};
```

running this in wordpress I get `403 forbbiden' on the url for the folder before i can even test if this is working

Comment: seems like you're overriding the $ object. remove it from the argument

Comment: in place of '$'  try jQuery , object , $,ajax to jQuery.ajax({

Comment: fixing that helped solve the immediate error, but now getting 403 forbidden on the folder url

Comment: should i not be running all of this code inside the `window.onload` function?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have added reference of JQuery inside your `<script>` tag. JQuery Library is missing.

`<script src="../../jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

For your reference: [$.ajax is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528929/ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: it was loaded the entire time so that is not the issue here

Answer (score -1):

Try this code if it work for you.

```
window.onload = function($) {
var folder = "images/preload";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        //go through each item in folder
        $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
            //take each item and run into the normal preload method
            setTimeout(function() {
                // preload images
                var $img=$("<img />",{"src":filename});
                $('#target_id').append($img);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
});  
};
```

Comment: i do not agree with your method. when trying to scale this script, you would be appending thousands of images into one div doesn't make sense to me. i do not think appending to a `display:none` div is the right approach here

Answer (score -1):

You can solve 403 error by adding:

Options +Indexes

On .htaccess file.